# SQL Exception trying to add an existing user when context.SaveChanges() on a different table

Tags: c#, sql-server, model

I am trying to add an entry to a table that holds a users browsing history information. However, when trying to save the addition an SqlException is thrown:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.AspNetUsers' with
>   unique index 'UserNameIndex'. The duplicate key value is
>   (exampleUserName). The statement has been terminated.

A user is has many browsing histories but a browsing history can only be attached to one user so there is a user as part of the BrowsingHistory DataModel:

```
namespace DataModels
{
    [Table("BrowsingHistory")]
    public class BrowsingHistory
    {
        [Key]
        public int BrowsingHistoryId { get; set; }

        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        public int DeviceId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual AspNetUsers User { get; set; }
        public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It is to note that I am using the Microsoft Identity classes for my authentication. The user class looks as follows:

```
namespace DataModels
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    [Table("AspNetUsers")]
    public class AspNetUsers
    {
        public AspNetUsers()
        {
            BrowsingHistories = new HashSet<BrowsingHistory>();
            Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
            AspNetUserClaims = new HashSet<AspNetUserClaims>();
            AspNetRoles = new HashSet<AspNetRoles>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
        public bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LockoutEndDateUtc { get; set; }
        public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
        public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string HouseName { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
        public string Town { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<BrowsingHistory> BrowsingHistories { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public virtual ShoppingCart ShoppingCart { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserClaims> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AspNetRoles> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The error occurs when trying to save the addition in the repository. On the _context.SaveChanges() line the method below.

```
public void CreateBrowsingHistoryEntry(BrowsingHistory bhe)
{
    _context.BrowsingHistory.Add(bhe);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ok, so it looks like you are adding a record to your `AspNetUsers` table, and your database has a constraint that `UserNameIndex` needs to be unique. You seem to be violating that constraint.

Comment: I am trying to add a Browsing History record which belongs to a AspNetUser. I don't understand why it is trying to add a new AspNetUser record.

Comment: Is the user object in your BrowsingHistory bhe a new object (with Id = 0)? May be the framework is trying to insert the user first to maintain referential integrity?

Comment: I have changed my code so that the BrowsingHistory entry is now added to the User. Still doesnt save